# Extending Isomorphisms

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, ring-isomorphism

Let $E$ and $F$ be fields, and define the map $*^{\sigma} : F[x] \rightarrow F'[x]$, which simply applies $\sigma$ to the coefficients of a polynomial $f(x)$. It is an isomorphism of rings.

Let $\sigma : F \rightarrow F'$ be a field isomorphism, and let $f \in F[x]$ be irreducible. Let $F(\alpha)$ be the field generated by $\alpha$ over $F$.

If $\alpha \in E/  F$ is a root of $f(x)$ and $\alpha' \in E'/F'$ is a root of $f^{\sigma}(x)$, then we can extend $\sigma$ to $\sigma' : F(\alpha) \rightarrow F'(\alpha')$, with $\sigma'(\alpha) = \alpha'$.

Now, while trying to prove this, I did the following;

I know that  $\frac{F[x]}{<f>} \simeq F(\alpha)$ and $\frac{F'[x]}{<f^{\sigma}>} \simeq F(\alpha)$. Let $\mu$ be the map for the first isomorphism and let $\gamma$ be the map for the second isomorphism.

I can then define a function $\tau : \frac{F[x]}{<f>} \rightarrow \frac{F'[x]}{<f^{\sigma}>} $ by sending $g(x) + <f> \rightarrow g^{\sigma}(x) + <f^{\sigma}>$, which is an isomorphism.

So there is an isomorphic map from $F(\alpha)$ to $F'(\alpha')$ given by the composition of $\gamma(\tau(\mu^{-1}(\alpha))$.

In order to check that we've extended $\sigma$ to $\sigma'$ and $\sigma'(\alpha) = \alpha'$, we need to know what the maps $\mu$ and $ \gamma$ are. How are these maps defined?

Also, what does extending an isomorphism mean? How would one check that $\sigma$ has been 'extended' to $\sigma'$?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Are you sure your map from $F(\alpha) \to F'(\alpha')$ isn't given by $\gamma \cdot \tau \cdot \mu^{-1}$, and not $\tau \cdot \gamma \cdot \mu^{-1}$?

Comment: Yes, you’re right, I’ll edit it now.